# How to use Record Set to prepopulate table in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2, model

I'm running ArcGIS 10.2.1. and am trying to prepopulate a record set in model builder. The record set is set as a Modeled Parameter. 
[image: Beginning of my model]

I open the record set enter the information into the table and hit "apply" then hit "OK." 
[image]

However when I open it again, all the information that was previously enter is gone. The  model tool dialog box also shows that there is no information in my record set. What can be done to rectify this?? I need to prepopulate this table but still have it be easily editable from the tool dialog box. This should be working but it isn't.

Comment: I have not tried using a Record Set with ModelBuilder before and am trying to get to the same point where you are stuck without success.  In my case the Record Set variable is greyed out where I would expect to be able to choose a table for the record set schema to be inherited from.  Would you be able to edit your Question to provide additional details of the exact steps that you have performed, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo @ I just followed the outline given http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_Feature_Set_and_Record_Set/002w00000023000000/   but the table didn't prepopulate.